# Variable time_zone can't be set to the value of NULL

Tags: mysql, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have a fairly new set up of WampServer and when I use the source command for a new database:

```
source path/to/database.sql
```

It all seems to come up as

```
Query OK
```

Except I get this set of errors at the end:

```
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘time_zone’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘sql_mode’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘foreign_key_checks’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘unique_checks’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘character_set_client’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘collation_connection’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable ‘sql_notes’ can’t be set to the value of ‘NULL’
```

I have set up WAMP environments before and didn't have these errors.

Comment: Unless you can paste in some code from that problematic database dump, this is a server software problem that's outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Remember database dumps are generally just plain text SQL even if compressed, so it should be easy to open them up and search for things like `time_zone`.

Comment: sure ill add code, but this isnt a databse dump, I loaded a database in using source command

Comment: Whatever you want to call it, it's still a database dump if you can import it into the database with the `source` command. What is the *content* of that file in relation to `time_zone` for example?

Comment: Are you using the 32bit or 64bit WAMPServer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the 64bit WAMPServer, there was a little bug in the 64bit version.

Edit the `my.ini` file and change the section heading from

```
[wampmysqld]
```

to

```
[wampmysqld64]
```

The heading has to match the service name that WAMPServer installs MYSQL as and in the 64bit version the MYSQL service is called `wampmysqld64`